# SQL: INTO OUTFILE Error: File /data.csv already exists

Tags: php, mysql, sql, apache, xampp

I am trying to export sql query result to a file so that I can provide user a download link to download. But I am getting some issues:

Issue 1: After execution I could not find data.csv in the root folder.

Issue 2: If I try again then it says that file already exists.

I am using following code:

```
 $query = <<<EOL
   SELECT * FROM data
   INTO OUTFILE '/data.csv'
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
   ENCLOSED BY '"'
   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
EOL;

 $result = mysql_query($query);
```

Solutions I want:

1- I need to know from where I can locate file.

2- I need to be able this csv file through php after execution.

Details about the Environment I am using for this script:

- Local Host
- Xampp (Apache & MySQL)
- Operating System: Windows 10

Comment: Which operating system you use?

Comment: sidenote: there appears to be a space before your `EOL;` - if that's part of your real code, remove it.

Comment: have a look in the sites DocuemtRoot folder

Comment: `INTO OUTFILE '/data.csv'` try a relative path instead. You're using a full system path method as in `/var/home/usr/you/...`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Dont you mean he should use a full path, rather than a relative one?

Comment: @Makville either one should work, but their syntax is incorrect right now. But yea, in a way you're right.

Comment: There is no such folder var/home in my xampp folder

Comment: @NikunjChotaliya I am using Windows 10

Comment: use phpinfo() to find your system's root path. Mine was but an example. You also may not have permission to write to your root. Too many things can be a factor here. edit: on windows, syntax is c:\\folder\\file.xxx